# CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. Port not available. Exiting... while running selenium code on Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run the below code:

```
package automationFramework;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import appModules.SignIn_Action;
import utility.Constant;
import utility.ExcelUtils;

public class Apache_POI_TC {

    private static WebDriver driver=null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData,"Sheet1");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get(Constant.URL);
            SignIn_Action.execute(driver);
            System.out.println("Login Successfully, now it is the time to Log Off buddy.");
     driver.quit();
     ExcelUtils.setCellData("Pass", 1, 3);
     }}
```

But getting error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 17873
Only local connections are allowed.
[1525873930.811][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
[1525873930.816][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
Port not available. Exiting...
May 09, 2018 7:22:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'VAPW00000001503', ip: '10.96.62.163', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at automationFramework.Apache_POI_TC.main(Apache_POI_TC.java:25)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'VAPW00000001503', ip: '10.96.62.163', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:17873/status] to be available after 20004 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:175)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
    ... 12 more
```

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Please suggest how can i solve this

Comment: I am not getting why my question has been changed? i think because of the heading i am not getting a single answer

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Port not available. Exiting...
May 09, 2018 7:22:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
```

...implies that the **OS Unix Process** is unable to bind to the assigned free port within your system.

As per the discussion [**`Getting Invalid port error.`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1592) the error **`"Invalid port. Exiting..."** *occurs when the port assigned to chromedriver is less than 0 or greater than 65535.*

But, historically as per the discussions:

- [CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726) Port not available. Exiting… with chromedriver and Selenium 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743045/createplatformsocket-returned-an-error-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-0x2)
- [CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x27t6) Port not available. Exiting… in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838273/createplatformsocket-returned-an-error-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-0x2)

It had been observed that when both *ChromeDriver* and *GeckoDriver* are shared over the network, while initializing the *Browser Client* the following errors are observed:

- Sample A:

  ```
  Starting ChromeDriver 2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b) on port 12121
  Only local connections are allowed.
  [0.023][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  [0.023][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  Port not available. Exiting...
  Mar 11, 2017 9:13:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
  SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
  ```
- Sample B:

  ```
  [0.147][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726) 
  Port not available. Exiting...
  ```
- Sample C:

  ```
  [1525873930.816][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  Port not available. Exiting...
  May 09, 2018 7:22:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
  SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
  ```
- And even:

  ```
  //chromedriver
  [1530079175.164][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  [1530079175.165][INFO]: listen on IPv4 failed with error ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT

  //geckodriver
  An invalid argument was supplied. (os error 10022)

  //IEDriverServer
  Failed to start the server with: port = '2305', host = '', log level = '', log file = '', whitelisted ips = ''
  ```

### Solution

- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* or *GeckoDriver* are placed within the local drives of the host machine.
- Execute `netstat` command through *CLI* to see if you have reached limit of possible open connections or check if there is another application running on the given port.
- Check your firewall settings, there is a good chance that firewall configuration may be causing the issue.
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot* to free up the ports.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: the "solution" described here is just a list of general troubleshooting tips rather than an answer to the specific question.

Comment: Yes, right.. please any one help me in solving this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @liki How can you expect solutions when you are yet to work on the  solution already provided? I am sure you haven't tried anything out of this solution or else by now your issue possibly have been solved.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Yes you are right.. none of the solution worked for me. Then i just changed the chromedriver.exe file location from one drive to other it worked for me. So it was permission issue.

Comment: @liki Updated my Answers with references, let me know if that answers your question