# CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726) when trying to access chromedriver through network path

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I understand that the OS update caused to this issue not only for the chromedriver but also for the geckodriver.

Both chromedriver and geckodriver start without any problem when, the station that was updated, runs them locally (drive C:\ for instance). The issues arises when these two are found in a network path.

I have checked the permissions for the specific user, that runs these drivers, and I also checked the UAC and the Firewall but they don't seem to be related to the issue.

I prefer running the drivers from a network path for the sake of Maintenance. Because, I have several automation stations I want to centralize the infrastructure. This way I don't need to maintain the infrastructure in each one of the stations.

I am running both drivers with their default settings without using their options and I believe that maybe using these options can solve the issue.

Is someone familiar with these kind of issues ? Is it possible that by using the driver's options I can pass these issues safely ?

By the way I am running over a Windows 10 Pro Version: 1803 OS build: 17134.1

The chromedriver is version 2.40.565498 win32
and the geckodriver is v0.20.1-win64

The error messages that I get are:

**chromedriver**

```
[1530079175.164][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
[1530079175.165][INFO]: listen on IPv4 failed with error ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT
[1530079175.166][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
[1530079175.166][INFO]: listen on IPv6 failed with error ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT
```

**geckodriver**

```
An invalid argument was supplied. (os error 10022)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned:

- Both *ChromeDriver* and *GeckoDriver* starts without any problem when executed locally ( e.g. `C:\` drive)
- The issues arises when *ChromeDriver* and *GeckoDriver* are found in a network path.

Historically, as per the discussions:

- [CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726) Port not available. Exiting… with chromedriver and Selenium 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743045/createplatformsocket-returned-an-error-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-0x2)
- [CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x27t6) Port not available. Exiting… in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838273/createplatformsocket-returned-an-error-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-0x2)

It had been observed that both *ChromeDriver* and *GeckoDriver* when shared over the network, while initializing the respective *Browser Clients* the following errors were observed:

- Sample A:

  ```
  Starting ChromeDriver 2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b) on port 12121
  Only local connections are allowed.
  [0.023][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  [0.023][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  Port not available. Exiting...
  Mar 11, 2017 9:13:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
  SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
  ```
- Sample B:

  ```
  [0.147][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726) 
  [0.147][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x27t6) 
  Port not available. Exiting...
  ```
- Sample C:

  ```
  Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 17873
  Only local connections are allowed.
  [1525873930.811][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  [1525873930.816][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  Port not available. Exiting...
  May 09, 2018 7:22:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
  SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
  ```
- And even:

  ```
  //chromedriver
  [1530079175.164][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
  [1530079175.165][INFO]: listen on IPv4 failed with error ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT

  //geckodriver
  An invalid argument was supplied. (os error 10022)

  //IEDriverServer
  Failed to start the server with: port = '2305', host = '', log level = '', log file = '', whitelisted ips = ''
  ```

### Solution

So a generalized solution would be to access *ChromeDriver* and *GeckoDriver* by putting them into the local drives of the host machine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is true only when the OS that I rely on is Windows. Right ? By the way, my Windows 7 stations don't show the same issues. Isn't there any setting that will let me pass through the Windows Security ? I directed my IT Manager to request Microsoft's support with this issue once I understood that in the Past Windows 7 also raised its security level during one of the updates

Comment: @MosheS. I am afraid. I am not sure about the **Windows Security** stuff.

Comment: I will keep on looking for the good practice of running the webdrivers. I would like to keep them in a centered place and not locally on each the LAB stations

Comment: From my research I understand that there must be a way to run the webdrivers from a network path. I am still missing something but I think that by setting geckodriver options (some options that relate to its path) for instance I can succeed in running it from the network path. I have tried to do it both with chromedriver and geckodriver but still didn't get the required solution. I assume that I am doing something wrong