# Is it possible to set chrome webdriver file as URL?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code to set system properties:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Is it possible to store chromedriver executable within GitHub and use it in different projects? Something like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "https://path_to_file/chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: You could create a project that contains the various libraries and drivers related to Selenium and then include that project in your other projects so that you only have to maintain a single project as far as driver versions, etc. I wouldn't necessarily recommend this but you could do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726) when trying to access chromedriver through network path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056121/createplatformsocket-returned-an-error-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-0x2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open source [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) may be the closest solution to what you are asking for.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

This code will take care of downloading the right webdriver executable for your platform if needed and setting up the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible because :

WebDriver using protocols to communicate with browser and It known as`WebDriver JSON Wire Protocol`, which is actually a `RESTful` web service using `JSON` over `HTTP`.

Here is a explanation of how it works  : 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

So, using the driver as you want, you should run that `driver.exe` on external source and you should communicate with it via `selenium`. 
**There is only way to do what you want is improving and adding so much codes to selenium's source code.**

Answer (score 0):

First of all `hhttps://path_to_file/..` is an [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL), conversationally termed a **web address** is a reference to a [web resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource) that specifies its location on a computer network and a mechanism for retrieving it. A URL is a specific type of [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier). [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) enables/allows the client application (usually a web browser) to create HTTP requests containing the name of the web site it wants to contact for information exchange.

---

### chromedriver executable location

In [Troubleshooting - ChromeDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#troubleshooting) it is mentioned that,

> *The path to the chromedriver executable must be set by the `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property* and the chromedriver binary must be in the system path.

So, *Selenium*'s client expects the *WebDriver* executable to be in `PATH` i.e. the location of the *WebDriver* executable to be added within the *OS* native `PATH` variable.

---

### Conclusion

So it can be concluded that *it won't be possible to store the WebDriver executable within GitHub and use it in different projects*.

---

### trivia

Even *WebDriver* executable e.g. *ChromeDriver* or *GeckoDriver* won't get initialized if they are accessed from a network path. You can find a detailed discussion in [CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726) when trying to access chromedriver through network path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056121/createplatformsocket-returned-an-error-an-invalid-argument-was-supplied-0x2/51061531#51061531)

Comment: The driver doesn't have to be in PATH ... it just has to be in PATH if it's not fully specified when setting the property. The first half of this answer is explaining something OP already knew... he called it a URL.. why are you explaining what a URL is? This question should have been dup'd to the link in your trivia section.